# VBA Excel Protect comments

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

In a tracker for one team, I created a macro for adding comments anytime there's a change in any cell.

All works great, but there are concerns regarding the fact that anyone may remove such automatically created comment.

I searched nearly everywhere, yet could not find any solution to how protect comments from editing and from deleting.

I work on Excel 2010.

Comment: As a workaround, instead of comments, you may export the changes to a database. Thus, noone would be able to remove them. Or Put the comments in a very hidden worksheet, where your colleagues will not be able to see them.

Comment: Carrying on from @Vityata comment - you could use the `Selection_Change` event or some other mechanism to grab the change details from the hidden sheet and populate a comment on the cell.  If they delete the comment then it will just reappear next time they select the cell.

Comment: Comments are considered objects in Excel. You can choose to keep objects locked or unlock them when you protect the worksheet - they are locked as default.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But all these seem to be workarounds, is there truly no way of simply locking comments from editing?